# Google data mining tool

Tags: data-mining

I recently read about a new Google-code hosted (open source) project from Google that allows you to perform data mining and analytics on various input files. There was even a video showing the user importing an Excel file and filtering on various conditions. However I cannot find it now even after looking for several hours, does anyone know the name of this project?

Comment: Abdullah, please check out the new answer for your question "disabling uac programmatically" - yes, it is possible and you were incorrectly convinced that it was not!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Original

Google Refine http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/

## Update (2013/12/02)

`Google Refine` is now `OpenRefine` http://openrefine.org/

> Please note that since October 2nd, 2012, Google is not supporting actively this project which have been rebranded to OpenRefine. Project development, documentation and promotion is now fully supported by volunteers.

Repository location:
https://github.com/OpenRefine

Answer (score 5):

- For Classification and Prediction, [Google Prediction API](https://cloud.google.com/prediction/docs/)
- For operations on very large data set, [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/)
- For Data Cleaning and Transformation, [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine)